# What is wrong with my syntax calling a stylesheet (css) from an FXML file?

Tags: javafx, fxml, java-8

I am working in NetBeans 8, with Java 8 / JavaFX and FXML.

In the first controller (an AnchorPane) in my FXML document, I have this, that works:

```
stylesheets="file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/NetBeansProjects/MyApp/src/myApp/myStyle.css"
```

However, when I attempt to replace that with any type of relative path, I get the following error at runtime:

```
com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
WARNING: Resource "myStyle.css" not found.
```

I tried

```
stylesheets="myStyle.css"
stylesheets="file://myStyle.css"
stylesheets="./myStyle.css"
stylesheets="css/myStyle.css"
```

(where I put a copy of the css file in a subdirectory from where it was)

...and maybe 50 other permutations. Every time I get the same error.

The reason I care is that I am having a second problem. In the first version, that works on my machine... when I take my jar file to another machine, the css is not applied when the application is run... It's like the resource file isn't copied.

Help?

Thanks!

-Adeena

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me consider your project structure as follows

```
MyApp
  |
  |_ src
      |
      |_controllers (Controllers)
      |_view (FXML)
      |_style (css)
          |_myStyle.css
```

You can specific the relative path in the FXML using

```
<stylesheets>
   <URL value="@../style/myStyle.css" />
</stylesheets>
```

In your controller, you can add it as follows

```
layout.getStylesheets().add(getClass().
         getResource("/style/myStyle.css")).toExternalForm();
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for the stylesheets. Any other advice about referencing files in general? I'm having a different, but similar issue with referencing files. My file is in the same location as the src java, but "filename.jpg" (it's not a jpg but something proprietary) doesn't work, but referencing the absolute path does.

Comment: Can you show me a piece of code. For loading images in styles folder I would use something similar `Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/style/edit.png"));`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't send this piece of code. The concept of getClass().getResourceAsStream("style/edit.png") doesn't work because it's only expecting a String.

Comment: @adeena The code I gave you is for loading images and not files. If its just files and not images that you are loading then you will first have to make a `File` and then read it. I am not sure what type of file it is, so I am actually in a fix how to help you out !

Comment: @adeena may be you could just tell me the `file type` that you are trying to read ?

Comment: It's a ".g" file.  It's a proprietary graphic.  :)

Comment: Never heard of the file type :P . But, IMHO, there must be some Java API to read such files !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48520/discussion-between-adeena-and-itachiuchiha)

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works for me:

```
<?import java.net.*?>

<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane" ... xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@myStyle.css" />
  </stylesheets>
</fx:root>
```

The css file is in the same package (folder) as the FXML. Also my root happens to be `<fx:root>`, I expect it to work the same for your `<AnchorPane>`.

Check out the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html), search for "Location Resolution" for details.