# Change JavaFX TableView font size

Tags: java, javafx

Hi I want to set Font on text inside in column in tablewView. How I can do it in Java this is my code. Thanks for help.

```
    private final TableView<AnotherBus> table = new TableView<>();

    TableColumn busNumberCol = new TableColumn("Linia");
            busNumberCol.setCellValueFactory(
                    new PropertyValueFactory<>("busNumber"));
            busNumberCol.getStyleClass().add("Times New Roman,40");

            tb.getStyleClass().add("Times New Roman");

            TableColumn courseCol = new TableColumn("Kierunek");
            courseCol.setCellValueFactory(
                    new PropertyValueFactory<>("nameBusStpo"));
            courseCol.setPrefWidth(200);
            courseCol.getStyleClass().add("Times New Roman");
            TableColumn departureCol = new TableColumn("Odjazd");
            departureCol.setCellValueFactory(
                    new PropertyValueFactory<>("busTimetable"));
            table.setItems(list);
            table.getColumns().addAll(busNumberCol, courseCol, departureCol);
            table.setPlaceholder(new Label(

""));
```

Comment: You want to change the Color of the Cell or the Color of Column Header?

Comment: @GoXR3Plus I want to that text will be bigger

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How to use the code below❓
>
> You can add it into an `external.css` file and then connect it to your app simple like this:

1)[What is wrong with my syntax calling a stylesheet (css) from an FXML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043650/what-is-wrong-with-my-syntax-calling-a-stylesheet-css-from-an-fxml-file/22048338#22048338)
2)https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/04/use-external-css-files-javafx/

> Below is some css code that can be used to modify the table look.Note that a lot more exist,for that you can check [modena.css](http://pastebin.com/D4Bk2rr6).

```
//Style of entire tableView
.table-view{
    /*-fx-background-color: transparent;*/
 }

 //Style of entire tableView when is getting focused
.table-view:focused{
    /*-fx-background-color: transparent;*/
}



//Style of each column header in the tableView
.table-view .column-header {
     -fx-background-color: transparent;
} 

//Style of each column header's background in the tableView
.table-view .column-header-background{
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#131313 0.0%, #424141 100.0%);
}

 //Style of each column header's label  in the tableView
.table-view .column-header-background .label{
     -fx-background-color: transparent; 
    -fx-font-weight:bold;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

//Style of each column in the tableView
.table-view .table-column{
    -fx-alignment:center;
}

 //Style of each table cell
.table-view .table-cell{
    -fx-font-weight:bold;
    -fx-font-size:15px;           //the font size you asked in the comments below
    /* -fx-text-fill:orange; */

}


//Style for each < non odd> row of table view
/* .table-row-cell{
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-background-insets: 0.0, 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0;
    -fx-padding: 0.0em; 
}

//Style for each <odd> row of table view
.table-row-cell:odd{
    -fx-background-color: orange;
    -fx-background-insets: 0.0, 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0;
    -fx-padding: 0.0em;  
}
*/

//Style of each entire row in the table view
.table-row-cell:selected {
   /* -fx-border-color:transparent firebrick transparent firebrick  ;
    -fx-border-width:2.0; */
}


//Style of each entire row in the table view when is hovered
.table-row-cell:hover {
    -fx-background-color:orange;
}

//Style of each entire row in the table view when is getting focused
.table-row-cell:focused {
    -fx-background-color:purple;
}
```