# JavaFX table contours of the table

Tags: java, javafx

Hi could you help me how I can do contours of the table. I want that all rows in table have contours .Thanks for help. My table look like this :

```
TableColumn busNumberCol = new TableColumn("Linia");
        busNumberCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("busNumber"));
        busNumberCol.setPrefWidth(tb.getPrefWidth()/5);

        TableColumn courseCol = new TableColumn("Kierunek");
        courseCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("nameBusStpo"));
        courseCol.setPrefWidth((tb.getPrefWidth()-tb.getPrefWidth()/5)/2-1);
        TableColumn departureCol = new TableColumn("Odjazd");
        departureCol.setPrefWidth((tb.getPrefWidth()-tb.getPrefWidth()/5)/2-1);
        departureCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("busTimetable"));
        table.setPrefHeight(tb.getPrefHeight());

        table.setStyle("-fx-background-color: orange");
        table.setPrefWidth(tb.getPrefWidth());
        table.setItems(list);
        table.getColumns().addAll(busNumberCol, courseCol, departureCol);
        table.setPlaceholder(new Label(""));
```

Comment: Add this class selector to you stylesheet: `.table-row-cell { -fx-background-color: blue, -fx-background; }`. The result should be horizontal blue lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use:

```
.table-row-cell{
      -fx-border-color:red;
      -fx-border-width:1.0;
      /* -fx-background-color */
    }
```

Mention that it this adds a border around every row.For background color you can uncomment the above with `/* -fx-background-color*/`

> Also

For more styling on TableView look [Change JavaFX TableView font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39512621/change-javafx-tableview-font-size/39514062#39514062)

Answer (score 1):

try this in the css(for me is working):

```
.table-row-cell{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, /*coloryouwant*/;
}
```