# Set a background image for a HBox - JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, styles

I can't set a background image for a Hbox.
I tried this:

```
HBoxName.setStyle("-fx-background-image: images/background.png");
```

in the initialize method and then I also tried adding the CSS style in Scene Builder: `-fx-background-image` and `url("images/background.png")`.
How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFX How to set scene background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738146/javafx-how-to-set-scene-background-image)

Comment: Where do I create the css file? In the source package of the project? and what I have to write in this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of ways to set a background image for your HBox,

**1. Using CSS**

- **Using `setStyle` method**

  Use `setStyle()` method to set a background image directly,

  ```
  HBoxName.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('images/background.png');" +
          "-fx-background-repeat: stretch;" +
          "-fx-background-size: 1000 700;" +
          "-fx-background-position: center center;");
  ```
- **Using external `CSS` file**

  You should create an external CSS file load it to your scene(or you can load CSS file to any control as well),

  ```
  scene.getStylesheets().add(
      this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("style.css").toString()
  );
  ```

  Add these styles in your `style.css` file,

  ```
  #HBoxName{
     -fx-background-image: url("images/background.png");
     -fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
     -fx-background-size: 1000 700;
     -fx-background-position: center center; 
  }
  ```

  **References**

  - [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)
  - [Apply CSS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/apply-css.htm#CHDGHCDG)
  - [CSS file on FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043650/what-is-wrong-with-my-syntax-calling-a-stylesheet-css-from-an-fxml-file/22048338#22048338)

**2. Setting [BackgroundImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BackgroundImage.html) using `setBackground()`**

You can set a background-image with programmatically as well.

```
BackgroundSize backgroundSize = new BackgroundSize(900,
        700,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        false);
BackgroundImage image = new BackgroundImage(new Image("image/background.png"),
        BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
        BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
        BackgroundPosition.CENTER,
        backgroundSize);

HBoxName.setBackground(new Background(image));
```